# Install any application as administrator

Tags: software-installation, administrator

I want to run IBALauncher app as administrator. After downloading the tar.gz file what should I do?... I am using ubuntu 16.04
Thanku

Comment: extract with `tar xf <filename>`, then run it with `sudo`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what this program is and where you got it from. Were there no installation instructions? @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne that won't work, the OP mentioned a `tar.gz` file, so you need `tar xzf filename.tar.gz`, and most like you also need to `./configure`, `make` and then `sudo make install` but we can't know unless we know the details of the program.

Comment: But I always do tar xf or xvf for tar.gz files and it works. Same for tar.xz